# Python Discord Bot "cannot connect to host" - Stays Offline

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating my first python discord bot with the latest version of python installed on Atom. I am currently following a tutorial on YouTube done in Python 3.6.5

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nW8c7vT6Hl4

The tutorial has been straightforward, as I pip installed discord and replicated the setup code shown in the tutorial. My code is here (the token will not be shown).

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')

client.run('insert token here')
```

When I run this program, I get this very long error message, which says that the bot cannot connect to the host discord.com:443

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1050, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1080, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 529, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1124)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ayush\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\discordbot.py", line 10, in <module>
    client.run('NzYzOTY2OTg3MzEwOTg5MzEz.X3_Zsw.lbaYvBEk1kR6A58lkF3mqz7jDVc')
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 708, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 687, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 650, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 499, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 291, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 480, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 980, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\ayush\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 938, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1124)')]
[Finished in 1.317s]
```

I have looked at all the similar questions on Stack that may solve this problem, however, the most relevant search simply just said the issue is a server-side problem.

There are two things that might come into consideration.

1. When I pip installed discord, it worked, however, the command prompt said afterward that I do not have the latest version of pip installed
2. Could it perhaps be a problem with the version of python. I am using the latest version, and the video tutorial I am following is python 3.6.5

I would appreciate any insight on this issue, as I am relatively new to Python. Thanks!

Comment: Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error

Comment: Can you please explain how the solution on that post would apply to my code? I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ayush

The author of the post has provided explanation in the post